# How to parse data from a file into a Hash

Tags: ruby, parsing

I am trying to parse and store some data from a file into a hash map, not using regular expressions but string comparison, and I am getting some errors I tried to fix but didn't solve the problem.

The file has a structure like:

```
"key" + "double colon" + "value"
```

in every line. This structure is repeated along the file, and every data has an ID key, almost everything has at least one "is_a" key, and may also have "is_obsolete" and "replaced_by" keys.

I'm trying to parse it like this:

```
def get_hpo_data(hpofile="hp.obo")
    hpo_data = Hash.new() #Hash map where i want to store all IDs
    File.readlines(hpofile).each do |line|
        if line.start_with? "id:" #if line is an ID
            hpo_id = line[4..13]  #Store ID value
            hpo_data[hpo_id] = Hash.new() #Setting up hash map for that ID
            hpo_data[hpo_id]["parents"] = Array.new()

        elsif line.start_with? "is_obsolete:" #If the ID is obsolete
            hpo_data[hpo_id]["is_obsolete"] = true #store value in the hash

        elsif line.start_with? "replaced_by:" #If the ID is obsolete
            hpo_data[hpo_id]["replaced_by"] = line[13..22]
            #Store the ID term it was replaced by

        elsif line.start_with? "is_a:" #If the ID has a parent ID
            hpo_data[hpo_id]["parents"].push(line[6..15])
            #Store the parent(s) in the array initialized before
        end
    end
    return hpo_data
end
```

The structure I was expecting to be created is a global hash in which every ID also is a hash with its diferent data (one string data, one boolean and an array with a variable length depending the number of ID parents of that ID term, but I'm getting the following error:

```
table_combination.rb:224:in `block in get_hpo_data': undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

This time the error is pointing to the `replaced_by` `elsif` statement, but I also get it with any of other `elsif` statements, so the code does not work parsing "is_obsolete", "replaced_by" and "is_a" properties. If I try deleting these statements, the code succesfully creates the global hash with every ID term as a hash.

I also tried giving default values for every hash but it does not solve the problem. I'm even getting a new error not seen before:

```
table_combination.rb:233:in '[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

at this line:

```
hpo_data[hpo_id]["parents"].push(line[6..15])
```

Here is an example of how the file looks like for two terms showing the different keys I want to take care of:

```
[Term]
id: HP:0002578
name: Gastroparesis
def: "Decreased strength of the muscle layer of stomach, which leads to a decreased ability to empty the contents of the stomach despite the absence of obstruction." [HPO:probinson]
subset: hposlim_core
synonym: "Delayed gastric emptying" EXACT layperson [ORCID:0000-0001-5208-3432]
xref: MSH:D018589
xref: SNOMEDCT_US:196753007
xref: SNOMEDCT_US:235675006
xref: UMLS:C0152020
is_a: HP:0002577 ! Abnormality of the stomach
is_a: HP:0011804 ! Abnormal muscle physiology

[Term]
id: HP:0002564
name: obsolete Malformation of the heart and great vessels
is_obsolete: true
replaced_by: HP:0030680
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! We need sample code that is _runnable_ and demonstrates the problem. You're asking us to write a test harness to prove/disprove your code and debug it, but that's your job. [ask] will help you understand what we need.

Comment: @theTinMan The question isn't perfect but it still does a good job at showing what the input is, what the problem is and what OP tried.

Answer (score 0):

There might be more errors hidden in your code, but one problem is indeed that your `hpo_data` doesn't have default values.

Calling `hpo_data[hpo_id]["replaced_by"] = line[13..22]` fails if `hpo_id` hasn't been initialized.

You could define `hpo_data` like this:

```
hpo_data = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = {'parents' => [] } }
```

and remove

```
hpo_data = Hash.new() #Hash map where i want to store all IDs
```

and

```
        hpo_data[hpo_id] = Hash.new() #Setting up hash map for that ID 
        hpo_data[hpo_id]["parents"] = Array.new()
```

Any time you call `hpo_data[hpo_id]`, it will be automatically defined to `{"parents"=>[]}`.

As an example:

```
hpo_data = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = {'parents' => [] } }
# => {} 
hpo_data[1234]
# => {"parents"=>[]} 
hpo_data[1234]["parents"] << 6
# => [6] 
hpo_data
# => {1234=>{"parents"=>[6]}} 
hpo_data[42]["is_obsolete"] = true
# => true 
hpo_data
# => {1234=>{"parents"=>[6]}, 42=>{"parents"=>[], "is_obsolete"=>true}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!! It worked like you said. I also had to get the variable hpo_id out of the scope of the block in order to work I don't know why, but mainly the problem was in the hash. I really appreciate your answer, I was really stuck in that part of the code.

Comment: @JesusJPG: True I didn't notice it. If you only leave `hpo_id` inside the `each do |line|` block, it will only be defined for the corresponding line, and will be `nil` for the following lines, even though you'll need it as a reference. Feel free to upvote/accept the answer if it solved your problem.